# Lumen/Laravel: count every nested relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

i've got these nested relationship in Lumen 8, i'm looking for an Eloquent solution, if it's possible, to show the count of each nested relationship.

Procedures ->(hasMany) Documents ->(hasMany) DocumentFiles

I want to count DocumentFiles but on Documents. (field document_files_count)

So if i've got 1 Procedure with 2 Documents with 1 File each, i want to have a **document_files_count** on every Document object counting 1.

That's like what i'm expecting to have when returning the Procedure Object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Exercitationem ea distinctio consectetur.",
    "description": "Deserunt perferendis impedit laboriosam nemo hic unde est et. Quia dolores tempora incidunt iste dolor fugiat harum quae. Ducimus sit quo ut recusandae rerum qui.",
    "expiry": "2021-05-31 04:51:15",
    "status": "hidden",
    "documents_count": 1,
    "documents": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "procedure_id": 1,
            "title": "docname",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum ",
            "document_files_count": 1
            "document_files": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "document_id": 1,
                    "path": "path_to_file",
                    "extension": null,
                    "size": 34020,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "procedure_id": 1,
            "title": "docname2",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum 2",
            "document_files_count": 1
            "document_files": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "document_id": 1,
                    "path": "path_to_file",
                    "extension": null,
                    "size": 34020,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also set an hasManyThrough relation into Procedure model to access document files data from Procedure.. but doing withCount(['documentFiles']) obviously give me the general procedure documents and not the files per document count.

```
public function documentFiles(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(DocumentFile::class, Document::class);
}
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `HasMany` (or reverse of it) relation, you can do `NAME_OF_RELATION_count`. In your case, it would be `documentFiles_count` and that would give you back the number of models that particular relation has.

So, let's say you want to get each number, you do something like this:

```php
$procedures = Procedure::with('documents.documentsFiles')->all();
$eachDocumentsFiles = collect();

foreach ($procedures as $procedure) {
    foreach ($procedure->documents as $document) {
        $eachDocumentsFiles->push($document->documentFiles_count);
    }
}
```

Have in mind that this code is not 100% performant, I just coded like that because I have no code to work with. But the magic is using `->relation_name_count`, in your case `->documentFiles_count`.

If this is not working, you will have to use [`withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) (but I am not sure if it is available in Lumen).